# What does this "and where possible localize" clause mean?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each violation.

This sentense is found in N1570, the latest draft of C11, which I cannot afford.

Comment: Most online dictionaries don't cost anything to access. [Localize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/localize) - verb - *to make local; fix in, or **assign or restrict to, a particular place**, locality, etc.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the OP's question is more to do with "where possible" than "localize".

Comment: It would have been a good deal clearer if *"where possible"* was in parentheses.

Comment: @Rathony: I think it's a bit pointless speculating on *exactly* what OP doesn't understand about this perfectly ordinary construction. It might be an acceptable question on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) if that issue were clarified, but for ELU I think it's just General Reference regardless. Btw - I agree with JHCL that your answer actually confuses things even more - it seems clear to me the writer here means ***identify*** the location of each violation, not ***confine*** each violation to a specific location.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thanks for your support, but my view has been changed a little now that I've learned what 'C11' actually [**is**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)). It's quite feasible that a 'violation' of a coding *standard* could, and should, be confined to as small an area (of code) as possible.

Comment: @JHCL No wonder the OP is confused. Anyway, I changed my answer back to the original. Thanks.

Comment: @JHCL: Over 40 years ago I wrote a Cobol program where a missing full stop after the keyword DATA DIVISION caused the compiler to generate several hundred pages of errors (every line of code after the actual error was also flagged up as containing dozens of errors). So I can see some benefit in "localizing / restricting" an error. But having just looked up C11 myself, I'm sure the intention is that compliant compilers should identify *where the error occurs*, not "confine" it (Why would you want that? So the rest of the program can still run if you avoid that erroneous section of code?).

Comment: I'll bow to your knowledge; but I'll just say that my previous take was based on the idea of a 'violation' as an *event*, and moreover one that had happened in the past. Now (in context) I see it more as a *situation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The intent is that an implementation should (1) ***identify the nature of
>   each violation*** and (2) ***localize each violation in places where it is possible (to localize it)***.

The direct object of the transitive verb *localize* is *each violation*. As the object is used for both "identify the nature of" and "localize", "*and where possible localize*" is inserted in the middle of the sentence.

[Localize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/localize) means:

> to find or identify the location of (something) [Merriam-Webster]